# Is there a way to create submodules in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, module

I am developing a website with laravel and I am using modules but I want to know if I can make it so that these modules have submodules
something like

```
laravel-app/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    vendor/
    modules/
      ├── Admin/
          ├── Assets/
          ├── Config/
          ├── Console/
          ├── Database/
              ├── Migrations/
              ├── Seeders/
         ├── Entities/
         ├── Http/
              ├── Controllers/
              ├── Middleware/
              ├── Requests/
              ├── routes.php
         ├── Providers/
             ├── BlogServiceProvider.php
         ├── Resources/
             ├── lang/
             ├── views/
         ├── Repositories/
         ├── Tests/
         ├── composer.json
         ├── module.json
         ├── start.php
         |──modules
            |──AdminConfig
               ├── Assets/
               ├── Config/
               ├── Console/
               ├── Database/
                 ├── Migrations/
               ├── Seeders/
               ├── Entities/
               ├── Http/
                 ├── Controllers/
                 ├── Middleware/
                 ├── Requests/
               ├── routes.php
               ├── Providers/
                 ├── BlogServiceProvider.php
               ├── Resources/
                 ├── lang/
                 ├── views/
              ├── Repositories/
              ├── Tests/
              ├── composer.json
              ├── module.json
              ├── start.php
```

I have made it that way by changing the files in the config/module.php but it does not run with the php artisan serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's documentation provides some information on the [directory structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure).

> The majority of your application is housed in the app directory. By default, this directory is namespaced under App and is autoloaded by Composer using the PSR-4 autoloading standard.

In other words, you can structure your app how you want as long as you follow [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Therefore, I would make your modules inside the app directory with proper PSR-4 namespacing.

Example:

```
namespace App\Module1\Services;
namespace App\Module2\Services;
namespace App\Services; //For common services
```

In my app, however, I prefer to make "module" inside the existing directories.

Example:

```
namespace App\Services\Module1;
namespace App\Services\Module2;
namespace App\Services; //For common services
```

Comment: So my psr-4 should be something like this
        `"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\":"Modules/",
            "Services\\":"MyModule/Services"
        }
    },`

Comment: @Mntfr depends what you want to do. If use the `App` directory as the base directory, you do not have to change your composer autoload. If you want to create new directories that will not be in `app`, you could add `"psr-4": { "Modules\\": "modules/" }` (No capital to modules directory according to your question)

Comment: I tried to do it that way but when I access the url it gives me: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: That its for main module

Comment: @Mntfr this is because Laravel is looking by default into the `App\Routes` directory for route. You have to `require` all your `Modules` route files such as `require /path/to/modules/module1/routes.php` in the `App\Routes`.

Comment: Thanks but in which file should I add the require in each module´s Http/routes.php?

Comment: app/http/routes.php

Comment: Now I get this InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 112: I am sorry to be a bother

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to organize your project this way. You can have module within app directories (See option 2 in my answer). It will be easier to do and I can't find a drawback to it. If you want to develop a package, you can look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages